Bucket cannot have public ACLs set with BlockPublicAccess enabled
I want to make cloudformation and S3 then put log in S3.
So my code is like this below
const bk = new s3.Bucket(this, `cm-st-cloudfront-bk`, { 
  bucketName: s3_name,
  removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
  autoDeleteObjects: true,
  blockPublicAccess: s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
  //
  encryption: s3.BucketEncryption.S3_MANAGED,
  versioned:true,
});

const oai = new cloudfront.OriginAccessIdentity(this, `my-oai`,{
  comment:`Access identity for ${targetEnv}`
});

const cf = new cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, `Website-${targetEnv}-Distribution`, {
  comment:`CF for resource S3 ${targetEnv}`,
  viewerCertificate: {
    aliases: [],
    props: {
      cloudFrontDefaultCertificate: true,
    },
  },
  errorConfigurations: [
    {
      errorCode: 403,
      responsePagePath: "/index.html",
      responseCode: 200,
      errorCachingMinTtl: 0,
    },
    {
      errorCode: 404,
      responsePagePath: "/index.html",
      responseCode: 200,
      errorCachingMinTtl: 0,
    },
  ],
  loggingConfig: {
    bucket: bk,
    prefix: "cloudfront/",
  },
});

In this setting,this error comes.
Bucket cannot have public ACLs set with BlockPublicAccess enabled

So I change
blockPublicAccess: s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
to
//blockPublicAccess: s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
However same situation happens.
Bucket cannot have public ACLs set with BlockPublicAccess enabled 

How can I solve this, and I wonder is it impossible for cloudfront to put log into S3 with Block public access is on?

Thanks to @Dhruv answer, I changed like this,
const bk = new s3.Bucket(this, `cm-st-cloudfront-bk`, { 
  bucketName: s3_name,
  removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
  autoDeleteObjects: true,
  blockPublicAccess: s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ACLS
  encryption: s3.BucketEncryption.S3_MANAGED,
  versioned:true,
});
bk.addToResourcePolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
  actions: ['s3:PutObject'],
  effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
  resources: [bk.arnForObjects('*')],
  principals: [new iam.ServicePrincipal('delivery.logs.amazonaws.com')],
}));
const oai = new cloudfront.OriginAccessIdentity(this, `my-oai`,{
  comment:`Access identity for ${targetEnv}`
});

const cf = new cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, `Website-${targetEnv}-Distribution`, {
  comment:`CF for resource S3 ${targetEnv}`,
  viewerCertificate: {
    aliases: [],
    props: {
      cloudFrontDefaultCertificate: true,
    },
  },
  errorConfigurations: [
    {
      errorCode: 403,
      responsePagePath: "/index.html",
      responseCode: 200,
      errorCachingMinTtl: 0,
    },
    {
      errorCode: 404,
      responsePagePath: "/index.html",
      responseCode: 200,
      errorCachingMinTtl: 0,
    },
  ],
  loggingConfig: {
    bucket: bk,
    prefix: "cloudfront/",
  },
});

Now this error occurs, Invalid request provided: The S3 bucket that you specified for CloudFront logs does not enable ACL access

This is because CloudFront needs write access to the S3 bucket in order to store the access logs.
You can configure the S3 bucket policy to allow write access only from the CloudFront logging service principal. You can modify your S3 bucket definition to allow CloudFront to write logs while still blocking public access:
// Allow CloudFront logging service principal to write access logs to the bucket
bk.addToResourcePolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
  actions: ['s3:PutObject'],
  effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
  resources: [bk.arnForObjects('*')],
  principals: [new iam.ServicePrincipal('delivery.logs.amazonaws.com')],
}));



Thank you very much, Now new policy is created for this, but another error The S3 bucket that you specified for CloudFront logs does not enable ACL access occurs.

Use blockPublicAccess: s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL in Bucket Configuration

Thank you, I used objectOwnership: s3.ObjectOwnership.BUCKET_OWNER_PREFERRED instead of blockPublicAccess: s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL and it works.
